# Unable to delete in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 5.2 and I am unable to delete article in laravel. Below is my view link:

```
<form method="DELETE" action="/article/{{ $article->id }}">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Below is my controller code:

```
  public function destroy($id)
{
     Article::destroy($id);
     Session::flash('msg','Article deleted successfully');
     return redirect()->back();
}
```

Below are route listing:
[image]

Comment: show your controller code what you wrote..

Comment: show your controller code what you wrote..

Comment: we need also your routes file

Comment: `method="DELETE"` is not a valid value in HTML. Should be either `POST` or `GET`.

Comment: Try change form method to `POST` and add hidden input `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">`.

Comment: Your `destroy` route looks fine. Try the code in my answer, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

HTML forms don't actually support any methods other than `GET` and `POST`. To get around this Laravel spoofs the method and then picks this up in the request.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#form-method-spoofing):

> HTML forms do not support `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` actions. So, when
>   defining `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` routes that are called from an HTML
>   form, you will need to add a hidden _method field to the form. The
>   value sent with the _method field will be used as the HTTP request
>   method

As such, you just need to alter your form like so:

```
<form method="POST" action="/article/{{ $article->id }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

You can also generate the `_method` with `{{ method_field('DELETE') }}` using Blade.

Comment: @AliRaza glad to hear it! Please accept the answer if it solved your problem and upvote it if you can.

Comment: No worries @AliRaza you can still accept answers. You get reputation for that too.

Answer (score 0):

In your view file what you need to do is...

```
<form method="POST" action="/article/{{ $article->id }}">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```